# Hibernate call DELETE from table after method end

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-delete

I have problem, and I don't know how to solve it.

I have entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_languagetree")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "languagetree_id"))
public class LanguageTree extends BaseObject {

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = java.lang.String.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "view_languagetree_to_stringlist")
    private List<String> relationship = new ArrayList<>();

    public LanguageTree() {
        //
    }

    public List<String> getRelationship() {
        return relationship;
    }

    public void setRelationship(List<String> relationship) {
        this.relationship = relationship;
    }
}
```

where `BaseObject` is

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "entity_id")
    private Long id;

    /**
     *
     * @return true if the entity hasn't been persisted yet
     */
    @Transient
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id == null;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Bean getBean() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Work with object - in my servlet, I am calling `jsVarTree()` like this:

```
String var = jsVarTree();
```

**My problem is**, that after method `jsVarTree` is finished, hibernate delete my `relationship` list from entity `LanguageTree`. I don't know why! I am not calling any delete and etc.. (**I AM SURE**, I SPENT A LOT OF TIME IN DEBUGER!)
:

```
@Override
public String jsVarTree() {
    TreeBuilder tb = new TreeBuilder(getLanguageList());
    return tb.getJsVarString(); // THIS METHOD IS ONLY GETTER !!!!
}

@Override
public List<String> getLanguageList() {
    LanguageTree lt = getLanguageTreeObject();
    return lt.getRelationship();
}

@Override
public LanguageTree getLanguageTreeObject() {
    long fakingId = languageTreeDao.getLastId();
    ServerLogger.logDebug("LAST FAKING ID: " +fakingId);
    return languageTreeDao.findOne(fakingId);
}
```

I found this log in loggor:

> HibernateLog --> 15:01:03 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - delete from
>   view_languagetree_to_stringlist where LanguageTree_languagetree_id=?

Can somebody tell me, why hibernate call delete over my table?

I saw a table in phpmyadmin..

```
TABLE IS FULL.
String var = jsVarTree();
TABLE IS EMPTY.
```

Table is deleted after `return tb.getJsVarString();` is finished.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Somewhere, in the code that you're not showing us, you're setting the relationship property to null, or you're clearing it, or you're replacing it by another empty list.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, I am removing elements from this list... But I am not saving using dao... What will be help me? For example? How to make some new instance of this list?

Comment: Then you're not understanding the basic principle of Hibernate: it returns managed entities. Changes made to the entities are written, automatically, to the database. This is one of the core principles of Hibernate. Don't modify the entities if you don't want them to be modified. Create a copy of the list if necessary: new ArrayList<>(list).

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for your help, now it working. Problem was in removing items from list.